# Как правильно сделать ассемблерную вставку

Tags: c, ассемблер, masm32

Есть код (переход из защищенного режима ядра) на asm:

```
mov     eax, cr0 ; прочитать CR0
and     al, 0FEh ; сбросить бит PE
mov     cr0, eax ; с этого момента мы в реальном режиме
ret
```

Пытаюсь сделать ассемблерную вставку:

```
            asm volatile("    mov     eax, cr0 ");
            asm volatile("    and     al, 0FEh ");
            asm volatile("    mov     cr0, eax ");
            asm volatile("    ret              ");
```

В итоге выдает ощибку:

```
procman/procman.c:100: Ошибка: слишком много ссылок на память для «mov»
procman/procman.c:101: Ошибка: слишком много ссылок на память для «and»
procman/procman.c:102: Ошибка: слишком много ссылок на память для «mov»
```

Comment: Верхний код на MASM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете компилятор GCC, то вы должны писать команды используя синтаксис AT&T.

Если вы используете компилятор Visual Studio, то вы можете писать на синтаксисе MASM, но записуйте команды в таком виде `__asm {}`

Т. е. :

`__asm {
    mov eax, cr0
    and al, 0FEh
    mov cr0, eax
    ret
}`